# Square Brackets beneath Content in Math-Mode

Tags: math-mode, brackets, underbrace

I need some help:

Is it anyhow possible in Latex to make some square brackets under some Math-Text like:

2x^2 + 4x - 3 = 0

|_____|

I know about the underbrace-command but I need square brackets.

I hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

[image]

with use of `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\underbracket{2x^2} + 4x - 3 = 0
\]
\[
\underbracket[0.5pt][5pt]{2x^2} + 4x - 3 = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

for more details see documentation for the package `mathtools`, page 13